# How to get resize events in Backbone view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, resize, handler

Using Backbone 1.1.2

I've tried doing

```
        ...
        return BaseView.extend({

            onResize: function(){
                Debug.log("resize");
            },

            onInitialize: function(){                
                $(window).on('resize', this.onResize,this);                    
            }
            ...
```

But I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'apply'` Other `$(...).on(...)` events works fine.

So I tried doing it the backbone way and my method never gets called.

```
        events:{
            'resize':'onResize'
        },
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(window).on('resize', _.bind(this.onResize, this))
```

Comment: Oh, Underscore. Is there anything you can't do? Any idea why normal jQuery context passing does not work in this case? It works for other simple cases/custom events, just not on window events.

Comment: I usually bind those in the view's `initialize` method: `_.bindAll(this, 'onResize');`  you can bind multiple functions in one line and manage them in one place.

Comment: Yeah, this is the "override with super call" of `initialize` I'm just wondering why jQuery fails at window events from within a view.